# Tensor n-mode product in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow2.0

The tensor n-mode product between a tensor [image] and a matrix [image] as defined [here](https://public.ca.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/pubs/pubfiles/SAND2007-6702.pdf) (section 2.5) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005612/tensor-mode-product) is denoted by [image] and is of size [image].

Is there a function in Tensorflow that implements this operation? If not, how could this be implemented with the current API? My searches for an answer regarding this have so far been unsuccessful.

Ideally I would envision a function taking X and U, as well as n as parameters and returning their corresponding n-mode product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily implement that with [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) for a fixed number of dimensions. If at least `n` is statically known (not a symbolic tensor, which should never be a problem in eager mode anyway), you can fiddle with strings to get a generic version:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def n_mode_product(x, u, n):
    n = int(n)
    # We need one letter per dimension
    # (maybe you could find a workaround for this limitation)
    if n > 26:
        raise ValueError('n is too large.')
    ind = ''.join(chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(n))
    exp = f'{ind}K...,JK->{ind}J...'
    return tf.einsum(exp, x, u)

# Test
x = tf.ones((2, 3, 4, 5))
u = tf.ones((6, 4))
n = 2  # n is zero-based here
out = n_mode_product(x, u, n)
print(out.shape)
# (2, 3, 6, 5)
```

You could also get the same result by moving the *n*-th axis of *X* to the end, then doing a (batched) matrix product with *U*<sup>T</sup> and finally returning the new last dimension to the *n*-th position, but I don't think it would be simpler to write nor faster.

Comment: Spot on, thank you @jdehesa for such a concise and elegant answer. I was not aware of `tf.einsum` and how flexible this function is.